# PHP insert into mysql database with 'WHERE field ' equal to my selection

Tags: php, mysql

i need insert new location to row with the name i choose from my drop down.
How can i connect between the name and the location?

```
<?php

 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM test';
 $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

echo "<select name='testform'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
 echo "<option value=>$row[name]</option>";

}
echo "</select>";


 ?>

<html>
<form action="indexx.php" method="POST">
<br>Locatio name:<input type= "text" method="POST"><BR>
<input type="submit" value="Insert" method="POST">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean UPDATE (one or more _existing_ records) instead of INSERT(ing a new record)?

Comment: We understand that your requirement need a update statement please find the below tutorial with example helpful [http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) [http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: method="POST" only has to be assigned to the <form /> tag. You can remove them from all your form elements.

Comment: @AlexBerger Have you got an id field in your table? Or something else that is unique for every name? (locatio)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form was submitted by giving it a name and checking if it is set in your PHP code. If it is set, it means that the user submitted your data entry form. Perform an INSERT statement with the value the user entered.

Sidenote: input-tags don't have an attribute "method". You can remove those.

You might want to read about the lifecycle of a PHP script and the usage of the $_POST array in PHP. The syntax of the INSERT statement can be found in numerous language specs or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed things up a bit and wrote the following code for you. Please tell me if this explains it a bit more.

#### The code you require

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    $query = "UPDATE test SET location_name='".$_POST['new_location']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['location']."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if (!$res) {
        die("Something went wrong");
    }
}

// This is the code to load the select options
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM test';
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$options = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $options[] = $row;
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <select name="location">
        <option value="0">--- Select an option ---</option>
        <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
            <option value="<?= $option['id'] ?>"><?= $option['name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select><br />
    New name: <input type="text" name="new_location"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Comment: i am trying select one of items from drop menu and update his location_name column

Comment: @AlexBerger Please edit your question and add the extra information there. Can you tell me what columns your table has?

Comment: Anew query that i am tryng  ------------$query = "UPDATE test SET `location_name` ='".$_POST['location_name']."' WHERE `name`= '".$option['name']."'" ;

Comment: id--name--location_name

Comment: i am trying populate drop menu -- succeseful

Comment: and add field (text field) with integer that is the new Location_name

Comment: @AlexBerger If you copy and paste the above code, this should work perfectly for you.

Comment: Can you give me a link from where i can learn about $_SERVER ?

Comment: You can learn more about predefined variables ($_SERVER) in the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php). If my answer helped you, do not hesitate to accept it as your answer.

Comment: @AlexBerger You should ask that in a new question.

Comment: this is the new question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324664/how-can-i-convert-a-name-to-id

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    $query = "UPDATE test SET location_name='".$_POST['new_location']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['location']."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if (!$res) {
        die("Something went wrong");
    }
}

// This is the code to load the select options
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM test';
$res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$options = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $options[] = $row;
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <select name="location">
        <option value="0">--- Select an option ---</option>
        <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
            <option value="<?= $option['id'] ?>"><?= $option['name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select><br />
    New name: <input type="text" name="new_location"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```