# How can i convert a name to id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying update an id that has a foreign key to another table of names. I have a drop menu and in the drop menu I have name from table NAME_TEST. I need to select the name but the insert that I want is:

```
INSERT INTO (test) values (the value that i need is the ID of selected name)
```

Code:

```
<html> <h1>Update form</h1></html>

                     <?php
                     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                     $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
                     $query = "UPDATE test SET                                               location_name='".$_POST['new_location']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['location']."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if (!$res) {
        die("Something went wrong");
    }
}

            // This is the code to load the select options
            $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM name_test';
            $res = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            echo "Choose setup";
            $options = array();


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $options[] = $row;
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"><BR><BR>
    <select name="location">
        <option value="0">--- Select an option ---</option>
        <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
            <option value="<?= $option['id'] ?>"><?= $option['name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select><br /><BR><BR>
    <B> New name:</B> <BR>  <input type="text" name="new_location"><br /><BR><BR>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Comment: do you mean you need the selected index from the drop menu?

Comment: selected name from drop menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` for this.  The idea is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO t(nameid)
    select nameid
    from names n
    where n.name = ?;
```

`t` is the table you want to insert into.  `names` is the table that has the name id and the name.

Comment: yes , insert into test ID of name.   The names from t.names

Comment: I am trying update TEST table but i need insert the id of  the name  selected from drop menu

Comment: $query = "UPDATE test SET name_id='".$_POST['new_location']."' WHERE name_test.id='".$_POST['location']."' LIMIT 1";